# "eval" blocked by CSP using on page-mod's contentScript

Tags: firefox-addon, eval, firefox-addon-sdk, content-security-policy

Im trying to create an extension that will interacts with github.
I need to use "eval" in my code but im keep getting blocked by the page CSP.
This is a simplified version of my code:

```
const pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod;

var contentScript = 'try {eval("console.log(\'hello from eval\')");} catch (e) {console.log("page mode " + e.message);}';

pageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScript: contentScript ,
    contentScriptWhen: "start"
});
```

Can someone help me solve the problem?

Comment: Your code works for me when I open google.ca. What error exactly do you get?

Comment: The message im getting is "page mode call to eval() blocked by CSP". Going to google.com also works for me the issue appears when i go to https://github.com/

Answer (score 1):

This because the Content Security Policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives

Usually 99% of the time, the usage of `eval` can be replaced with something else. If you give the context (why you need the eval), we can try to suggest an alternative.
That's the easy way.

The hard way, is intercept the response from github, to remove that header, using [the observer notification "http-on-examine-response"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Observer_Notifications), here there is a [full example](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/nsitraceablechannel-intercept-http-traffic/) but you can probably have a simplified version of it.

Personally, I would try to avoid using eval, it's usually easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though I agree that using eval is usually considered "evil", with my add-on design I'm forced to use it.

I had a look at the SDK implementation of the PageMode module and as far as I can see it uses 
Components.utils.Sandbox and Components.utils.evalInSandbox to run the contentScript on a page.
If the code is "sandboxed" form the page, then I see no reason for it to be blocked by the page's 
CSP. On Chrome (which also "sandboxes" the content script from the page), I have no problem using eval. Please can you explain why the "sandbox" code is being affected at all?

Comment: About Google Chrome, I don't know if and how implement CSP, so I can't answer. About the Add-on on Firefox, the answer is simple: the content script is executed with the same privilege of the host page, that is lower than the add-on code, that runs in browser environment (chrome, and therefore with the system principals). I'm not saying that `eval` is considered "evil", I'm just saying that you probably can obtain the same result doing something better, or different. But without knowing what you want to achieve, we can't suggest to you any good alternatives, except the one I gave.